# Recursive function acts weird in php

Tags: php

I got stuck when I learned about recursive functions in PHP. I know recursive function are those which are being called by itself. My code is:

```
function addition_no($x,$y) {
  if($x==0) {
    return $x;
  }
  return addition_no($x+$y);
}
echo addition_no(1,2);
```

When I tried executing this code I get:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for addition_no(), called in
>   /web/com/13978781902261/main.php on line 6 and defined in
>   /web/com/13978781902261/main.php on line 2

What i need is to add two numbers via recursion.

Comment: Why do you need recursion here? Is it some kind of homework?

Comment: nah ..i just did it to learn how recrusive function works

Comment: try changing your function declaration to `function addition_no($x,$y=null){`, that way argument 2 is optional, which would allow `return addition_no($x+$y);` to be a valid call to your function.

Comment: Note, `return addition_no($x+$y);` will result in an infinite recursion as `$x+$y` will never make `$x==0`

Comment: your code didnt worked ...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this code in order to summarize values in an array using recursivity is:

```
<?php

//values to add
$add = array(5,4,4,6,7);


function addval($add,$pos) {
    if($pos == 0) {
        return $add[0];
    }
    else {
        return $add[$pos] + addval($add,$pos-1);
    }
}
//last position in vector
$last_position = count($add)-1;
echo addval($add, $last_position);
?>
```

Comment: this helped ...thanks man ..and why did you create count($add)-1 ?

Comment: Because the last position in a vector with 5 elements would be 4 (positions starts from zero), and count function give you the total number of elements (5).

Comment: btw this is an array sum not according to my question ..anyway dont worry i have accepted it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
return addition_no($x,$y);
```

You have to check any condition for recursive function otherwise it will be infinite recursion..

Comment: This will cause infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

The warning is appropriate as you call the function inside it self with a different argument structure. 
Try the factorial recursive function to learn how it works:

```
<?php

// Initiating Recursion
echo factorial(5); 


//Recursive Function Definition with 1 parameter
function factorial($number)
{
    //Break condition for recursion 
    if($number==1)
        return $number;

    //Fetch and Stack Recursion
    return  $number*factorial($number-1);
}
```

So, you get the basic recursion, in simple English, as :

```
factorial(n) = n x factorial(n-1) = n x (n-1) x factorial(n-2)
```

For You particular case, you actually don't need a recursion as your arguments are not relying on the previous argument result. However, for the sake of learning, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

//Summation
function summation($x) {
  if($x==0) {
    return $x;
  }
  return $x+summation($x-1);
}

echo summation(5);



//Summation with 2 step
function summation($x,$y) {
  if($x<1) {
    return $x;
  }
  return $x+summation($x-$y,$y);
}

echo summation(5,2);
```